# How can we know that all asynchronous operations, all callback are done, and wait for them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

The following code,
read a file with documents sorted by categories, and values desc,
and modify the documents with the highest value for each categories.

following, the code :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://WRKHAL02:27017/test', function(err, db) {
if(err) throw err;

function (cbUpdate(err,updated) {
    if(err) throw " \n cbUpdate \n" + err;
    console.log(" Successfully updated " + updated + " Document");
}

var theFile = db.collection("theFile");
var cursor = theFile.find({});

cursor.sort([["State",1],["Temperature",-1]]);

currentState = "empty";
cursor.each(function(err,doc) {
    if(err) throw " \n -*- cursor.each error -*- \n" + err;
    if (doc == null) {
        console.log(" \n doc == null ; End Of File \n ");
        here use to be the db.close();
    }
    else {
        if (currentState != doc.State) {
            console.log(doc._id);
            console.log(doc.State);
            console.log(doc.Temperature);
            var myquery = {};
            myquery['_id'] = doc['_id'];
            var myupdate = {$set:{"month_high":true}};
            theFile.update(myquery, myupdate, cbUpdate);
            currentState = doc.State;
        }
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(" TimeOut ");
    db.close();
}, 3000);
});
```

The problem is I don't know when all asynchronous operations are ended.
The read process can finish first or the update process can finish first (if there is many documents to read after the last update).
So I don't know when to close the DB.

How can I know that all asynchronous operation and all callback are done, and wait for them.
I read about "promise"  but it look like the hell to write something efficient and clean with that.

The only but no realistic way I found to test this small piece of code is to add a wait loop at the end.

The asynchronous feature seem to change a very simple algorithm into some deep perplexity.

Thanks.

Comment: have a counter initialised with zero, increment it before calling `.update()` and decrement in update callback. Zero counter == all async operations done.

Comment: Use promises or the `async` module.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you set a global variable in the `window.open_procs = 0;` then at the beginning of each ajax call you increment it, then in the function you execute as the result of each ajax call, decrement it.

After you kick off the last ajax call then start your watcher process in a timeout that checks the window.open_procs to equal 0 before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Would definitely recommend learning Promises. [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is the method you'd be looking for in this case, to register a callback for when an array of promises all complete.

There's a few mongodb client wrapper libs on npm that automatically Promise-ify MongoClient requests:

- https://github.com/Submersible/node-magnolia
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-promise

Related:
http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/